# JsPDF repeating first row on every new page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am saving a PDF using jspdf.I have tables in my HTML and that tables do not have headers.But feature of JsPDF is automatically repeating the first row of my table on every page and they are overlapping.I do not want headers on every new page.Is there any way to do so.Attaching a screenshot of [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpSXe.png).Thanks in advance!!!

```
$scope.SavePage = function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);
    margins = {
        top: 200,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    specialElementHandlers = {
        '#ignoreComponent': function(element, renderer) {
            return true
        },
        '#ignorePage': function(element, renderer) {
            return true
        }
    };

var source = $('#pageInformationPdf')[0];

doc.fromHTML(source, margins.left, margins.top, {
        'width': margins.width,
        'pagesplit': true,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },
    function(dispose) {
        doc.save(pageName + '.pdf');
        }, margins);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

With newer version (3.x.x) you can use `willDrawCell` hook.
For example just to hide headers (additional logic can be applied):

```
willDrawCell (HookData) {
  if (HookData.section === 'head') {
    return false
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `drawHeaderRow` hook. Below is sample code

```
function generate() {
  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
  var elem = document.getElementById('table');
  var data = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);

  //Do not print the header if current page not the first page.
  doc.autoTable(data.columns, data.rows, {
    drawHeaderRow: function(row, data) {
      if (data.pageCount > 1) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  doc.save("table.pdf");
}
```

### html

```
<button onclick="generate()">Generate PDF</button>

<table id="table" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>IP-address</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">1</td>
        <td>Donna</td>
        <td>Moore</td>
        <td>dmoore0@furl.net</td>
        <td>China</td>
        <td>211.56.242.221</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">2</td>
        <td>Janice</td>
        <td>Henry</td>
        <td>jhenry1@theatlantic.com</td>
        <td>Ukraine</td>
        <td>38.36.7.199</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more in detail.I am printing a div that have multiple tables inside it. Here in answer what data refers to?

Comment: `drawHeaderRow`is no longer available on v 3.x. The changelog mentions to migrate to the new hook API but it's not obvious to me. Do you have an updated answer working in current release of the package? Thanks.