# jsPDF-autotables table has head in the end of the page and the full content is at the another page

Tags: javascript, typescript, jspdf-autotable

so as you saw at the title, basically im making a pdf but there sometimes that the table has no space at the page and it automatically creates another page with the table.
But it leaves the head of the table at the end of the page, here's a screenshot:
[image: The table head and the full table]
Here is the code of the table:

```
  autoTable(doc, {

  startY: tableHeight + 5,
  theme: 'plain',
  styles: {
    lineColor: [0, 0, 0],
    lineWidth: 0.25,
  },
  head: [['Redespacho', 'Tipo frete', 'Valor frete']],
  body: [
    [
      values.redispatch! || 'N/A',
      values.redispatchShippingType! || 'N/A',
      values.redispatchShippingPrice! || 'N/A',
    ],
  ],
  didDrawPage: (data: any) => {
    tableHeight = (data as any).cursor.y
  },
  willDrawCell: function (data) {
    if (data.section === 'head' && data.pageCount !== data.pageNumber) {
      return false
    }
  },
})
```

If you guys could help, I'll be so thankfull.

I've tried [JsPDF repeating first row on every new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779903/jspdf-repeating-first-row-on-every-new-page), but erased all the heads